# IIS in windows 2019 HAproxy 504 gateway issue

Tags: iis, haproxy, 504

We have an haproxy device that load balances a number of devices. However starting 1/18 two  windows 2019 IIS servers have intermittently started responding to haproxy with a 504. This setup has been working flawlessly for some time and the ODD factor here is if I just disable the internal adapter on the two servers and enable it everything starts working again. There is no determinable time pattern. There is nothing in the IIS event viewer around the time the servers start throwing a 504. With no errors in the window servers I am not sure what to try next any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Might be a problem on your actual website running on IIS. Are the wbesites available (through localhost for example) when IIS starts responding with 504 to haproxy? Does a website restart in IIS also work like reseting the adapter?

Comment: Has there been a update installed then?